# Keras ValueError: input 0 is incompatible with layer flatten_11

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Attempting to follow the tutorial at https://blog.keras.io/using-pre-trained-word-embeddings-in-a-keras-model.html in order to train a model for a small amount of training data, using pre-existing word-embeddings.

The issue I am having is when I attempt to run the 1D Convnet, I get the error:

```
Input 0 is incompatible with layer flatten_11: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

The dimensions of my tensors are:

Shape of data tensor: (91, 1000)
Shape of label tensor: (91, 3)

The issue is with this part of the code:

```
sequence_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32')
    embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sequence_input)
    x = Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu')(embedded_sequences)
    x = MaxPooling1D(5)(x)
    x = Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu')(x)
    x = MaxPooling1D(5)(x)
    x = Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu')(x)
    x = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x)
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(3, activation='relu')(x)
    preds = Dense(len(labels_index), activation='softmax')(x)

    model = Model(sequence_input, preds)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='rmsprop',
                  metrics=['acc'])

    model.fit(x_train, y_train,
               batch_size=128,
               epochs=10,
               validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

Without flattening, it feeds back the error:

```
Error when checking target: expected dense_25 to have shape (33,) but got array with shape (3,)
```

I'm trying to work out where and what I need to change to ensure the dimensions are working correctly, however I haven't managed to work out what exactly I need to change. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should focus on the error without the Flatten, as you are already using 1D convolutions it wouldn't require flatten to pass to Dense.

The actual error is complaining that although the target is (3,) which are your labels, your final Dense layer is outputting 33 values. So it seems like `len(labels_index) == 33` and not 3 as you have in your data.

Comment: Altered the label creation to: `for text in texts:
        label_id = len(labels_index)
        labels_index[text] = label_id
        labels.append(label_id)` but now it feeds back that the array's shape is 34. Getting closer, but any idea what I need to change to fix it?

Comment: It sounds data specific, so I is difficult to tell. At least you know where the problem is, your number of labels do not agree with the model basically.